# HTML5 with Phonegap and JQueryMobile on Android - Swipe Problems

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, swipe

I'm facing some issues with the jQuery swipe functions. I simple want to swipe to the next page with this code:

```
<script>                                                                          
$('#dataPageOilLevel').live('swiperight',function(event){
  $.mobile.changePage("batteryStatus.html", { transition: "slideup"});
})</script>
```

at the end of my html5 document. 
The ID is right and the page link should work.

I get this LogCat, if I try to swipe:

webview "Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down"

What's strange is that the same code is working on the first page without problems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1746
http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-bug-miss-drag-as-we-are-waiting.html

Many of the Web Frameworks (JQueryMobile, Sencha Touch) will override the ontouchmove event which results in the warning since it never hit the touchdown event. I don't think you have to worry about this warning. I know I had this warning in the past and it never prevented the app from functioning correctly.

EDIT:
Try some of these
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/looking-for-a-complete-swiperight-swipeleft-example
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/need-example-of-swipeleft-swiperight-any-body-got-a-good-url
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/3/14/Using-swipe-gestures-for-navigation-in-jQuery-Mobile

Comment: But it does prevent the app from functioning correctly. It doesn't swipe the pages. Only the first, as mentioned!

Comment: On each of the pages, do you have a scroll?

Comment: I use this code with swipeleft on every page, but with different destination sides in: changePage("batteryStatus.html", { transition: "slideup"});

Comment: If you have a page that also has a scroll.
Example - lets say size of view is 400 x 600.
Page 1.
Simple page that takes full 400 x 600. No scroll since it doesnt overflow.
Should work fine.
Page 2. 
Page has text and other items that extend the content 200px below the view resulting in a scroll.
When you try to swipe, I would assume the scroll will take priority and you would not be able to finish a swipe.

Have you tried this in Chrome?

Comment: I didn't get it. But i started the app with the Page causing problems first! And it worked. So the page change cause the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: when you switch pages, are you sure the event is still valid? Add some debug "console.log('blah')" or "alert('blah')" and see if they are getting hit. The events may be getting cleared when you change pages (depending how its set up).

Comment: I call this on Method on every new page to register the functionality! Why should something be invalid?

Comment: Where should i add a debug statement? <script>                                    
 $('#dataPageBattery').on('swipeleft',function(event){ 
  $.mobile.changePage("oilLevel.html", { transition: "slideup"});                                  
 })                                   
</script>

Comment: <script>  $('#dataPageBattery').on('swipeleft',function(event){ $.mobile.changePage("oilLevel.html", { transition: "slideup"}); alert('blah')  })  </script>

Comment: I changed the ´.live() Method into .on() Method, because JQuery Framework 1.7. And now there are no more warning messages, but the swipe doesnt work. I load a first page and the swipe works. But every other page isn't working. I use the same code(with a different destination) to register the swipe functionality on every site.

Comment: Only the the page which opens at startup of the up functions. The other pages have not debug output at all. Is there a problem with  one .on() method on every page?

Comment: I can only add the possiblity to swipe to one page! Whats the matter here?

Comment: I use on first page: <script>                                                                       
 $('#dataPageOilLevel').on('swiperight',function(event){
   $.mobile.changePage("batteryStatus.html", { transition: "slide"});
   console.log('slideRight')   this one on the second page: <script>                                    
 $('#dataPageBattery').on('swipeleft',function(event){ 
 event.preventDefault();
  $.mobile.changePage("oilLevel.html", { transition: "slide"}); 
  console.log('slideLeft')
 })                                   
</script> but only the first works! why?
 })
</script>